# How do I create an HTML table with the following structure?

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create a table with the following structure.

[image]

I've been reading various sites and blogs to try to create this myself, but I have failed, terribly, and decided to ask for help here.

So far, I've been able to create the outer structure:

```
<table border='1' style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bak</td>
    <tr></tr>
    <td>Baz</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Foo</td>
    <td>Bar</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bak</td>
    <td>Baz</td> 
  </tr>  
</table>
```

But I can't figure out how to add the fields for *Name*, *Number*, and *Cost*. How do I nest it?

Comment: You can create another table inside the row of the main table

Comment: google about 'Rowspan', you will come to know how to produce the required table

Comment: @RohitBandooni: An example would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can find examples here http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rowspan` to cause a cell to appear in multiple rows, `headers` to link your data cells with header cells that aren't in traditional positions, and `tbody` to describe subdivisions of a table.

```css
table, td, th {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: solid black 1px;
  padding: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"> ...
            <th id="name_1"> Name
            <td headers="name_1"> ...
        <tr>
            <th id="number_1"> Number
            <td headers="number_1"> ...
        <tr>
            <th id="cost_1"> Cost
            <td headers="cost_1"> ...
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3"> ...
            <th id="name_2"> Name
            <td headers="name_2"> ...
        <tr>
            <th id="number_2"> Number
            <td headers="number_2"> ...
        <tr>
            <th id="cost_2"> Cost
            <td headers="cost_2"> ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use rowspan [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f2uw7Lqt/)

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cost</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>&nbsp</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cost</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

try fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atulbnar/6yqyfx2w/)

```
<table border='1' style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td> 
    <td>3</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">some</td>
    <td>Name</td>  
    <td>11</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cost</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

User `rowspan`

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Data Section 1</td>
    <td>Some Data 1.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Data 1.2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Some Data 1.3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Data Section 2</td>
    <td>Some Data 2.1</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Some Data 2.2</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Some Data 2.3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: User? :) I think you mean, use.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table border='1' style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In general way like this

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">2</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">3</td>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>17</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5b0c5d9/